# xpath matching wrong node

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml.html

The xpath

`//*[h1]`

shows different results when tried on python and Firebug. My code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/"
resp = requests.get(url)
page = html.fromstring(resp.content)

node = page.xpath("//*[h1]")
print node
#[<Element center at 0x7fb42143c7e0>]
```

But Firebug matches to a `<header>` tag which is what I desire.

Why is this so? How do i make my python code match `<header>` too?

Comment: are you trying to grab all `h1` nodes? why not simply use `.//h1`? `h1` is wrapped by `<center>` so what do you expect other than this?

Comment: @Anzel I am trying to get nodes that *contain* `h1`, not the `h1` itself.

Comment: I realized after re-reading your xpath. however your `resp` is `<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>`... so it is correct to return `<center>` node

Comment: Oh wow! But the url opens fine in a browser though! Any idea why its forbidden in `requests`?

Comment: I am guessing it's either missing UserAgent string, or perhaps you have logged in session somewhere in your browser ;)

Comment: indeed the UserAgent

Comment: Adding User-Agent of Firefox to headers did it, thanks! I still wonder why this url requires it when others didnt.

Comment: Glad it helps, its about the server configs which is out of your control, some do block requests without User-Agent, some don't. Sometimes the library you use may automagically add this for you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the User-Agent header and hence the response content returned **403 Forbidden**, add it to request and it works as expected:

```
In [9]: resp = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Test Agent"})

In [10]: page = html.fromstring(resp.content)

In [11]: node = page.xpath("//*[h1]")

In [12]: print node
[<Element header at 0x104ff15d0>]
```

Comment: Any idea why this url needs that? 'Cuz other urls worked fine without user-agent being explicitly mentioned?

Comment: @anupamGak, as I commented above, it depends on the server configs, some will block requests without User-Agent but some don't. And more importantly sometimes the libraries/tools automagically add one for you if it's not set explicitly that you may not be aware of :)